# How do I align bars in bar plot to the ticks of a line graph underneath in base R plot?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to graph a bar plot on top of a line graph but because of the nature of my line graph I have to use base r plots. The bars of the bar plot should align with the ticks of the line graph.

[image: My graph so far]

I've tried using space in the bar plot but it doesn't add any space between the y-axis and the left most bar. Here is my code so far:
`

```
        plot(OaM18.bootII, xlim=c(0,300), type='n',
             xlab="", ylab="Prey eaten",
             ylim=c(0, 300),xaxt="none",yaxt="none",
             family = "A")
        #X-axis labels
        axis(side = 1, #X-axis
             at = c(0,15,25,50,100,140,160,180,300), # Labels
             family = "A") #Font
        #y-axis labels
        axis(side = 2, # Y-axis
             las=2, # Rotate axis
             at = c(0,15,25,50,100,140,160,180,300), # Labels
             family = "A") #Font        
        #curves
        drawpoly(OaM18.bootII, col=adjustcolor("steelblue1", alpha.f=0.5), border=NA, lwd=2)
        lines(OaM18.bootII, col = "steelblue2",lty=1)
        
        par(new=T)
        barplot(bp.M18Oa$m.eaten, 
                names = bp.M18Oa$b.density,
                space=c(3,0.5,0.5,2,5,5,8,11),
                yaxt="none",xaxt="none")
        axis(side = 4)
```

`
Any help would be appreciated